# Wordpress Categories from Plugin

Tags: plugins, categories

I've got the Owl Carousel plugin installed, inside of it I can create some categories.

Now I'd like to have these Owl Carousel categories displayed on the site, not the regular categories. What you see on the site right now is the regular categories such as 'Uncategorised' which is created from within the POSTS area of wp-admin.

i tried using this but still just shows the wrong list of cateogies:

```
<?php wp_list_categories(
          $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'owl-carousel'
         )
 ); ?>
```

[image]
Regular categories page - [image]

Owl Carousel Categories page
[image]

Comment: I think they are making use of custom taxonomies, not build-in categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any argument of `post_type` in [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)

You should use `taxonomy` instead

```
wp_list_categories(
      $args = array(
          'taxonomy' => 'Carousel'  //Carousel is the taxonomy name your plugin use
     )
);
```

Comment: Do you know how I may be able to display only the images from the selected category with this plugin? Long shot but looking into this too. Currently it's just displaying everything.

Comment: @wharfdale I don't know how this plugin works. So, I won't be able to help. You should post your question to the plugin support forum: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/owl-carousel